# Booting using wrong xorg.conf causing black screen

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display

This is my first ever post as a new Linux user, so please be forgiving :)

```
1.
Summarize the problem
```

I changed code in xorg.conf, just one word, changing the section Device and then 'driver' from using AMD to "nvidia". I then saved the changes and rebooted. Now my laptop which was running the latest version of Ubuntu is now showing a black screen with one or a few lines of text.

```
2.
Provide details and any research
```

I have a ASUS TUF laptop with a Nvidia GPU and a Ryzen CPU. I need my computer to recognize my GPU and use it. I tried to make it do that by changing the `xorg.conf` file. That busted my laptop. I was looking all over to the fix for my main problem, my system not using my GPU, but I can't find that link now. Will keep looking.

```
3.
When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried
```

I've tried to SSH into my laptop but I don't think I ever set up the password for SSH.

Images of screen:
[image]

Sorry if this is confusing or if I didn't provide enough information. I'm loving learning Linux and really hope to save my Laptop.

Thanks for *ANY* help

Update: I've managed to boot into TTY2 and login :) used CTRL+ALT+F2 to do that. Then from there I used "sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf" and now I can fix my mistake. I need to change Driver "Nvidia" back to what it used to be. Which I can't remember... but will figure out :)

SOLVED: Yay!! I'm posting this from my laptop :) I was able to get it all sorted out!
I changed "nvidia" to "" ... nothing. Haha,because I couldn't find and couldn't remember what it used to be. Worked and my beautiful Ubuntu loaded up :D

THANKS!

Comment: You don't need to ssh. Try CTRL+ALT+F3 to get a tty (text-only) login.

Comment: Yes, thanks!!  I was able to do that and it worked :)